# exec() raises 'unexpected EOF' error when encountering the : character

Tags: python, parsing, exec, eof

In the program I am writing (a text-based rpg) I am going to include 'scripts', little pieces of code that add interactive functionality to the game (such as an NPC greeting you when you enter a room). Writing my own scripting language/parser seemed like a pretty big task so I thought I'd use Python code itself instead. It can do everything I will need out of the scripts so I started hacking away. For simple things like print statements or math, exec() is working fine. It's when I have a block that trouble arises. Here it is in action:

First - working code (from interactive shell):

```
>>> x = ''
>>> y = []
>>> while x != '@':
        y.append(x)
        x = raw_input(compile('''''', '<string>', 'exec'))

<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>name = 'Drew'
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>print 'Hello, %s' % name
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>@
>>> del x[0] # removes the empty field created by the first y.append(x)
>>> for line in y:
        exec line

>>> Hello, Drew
```

Now for the error (again from interactive prompt):

```
>>> x = ''
>>> y = []
>>> while x != '@':
        y.append(x)
        x = raw_input(compile('''''', '<string>', 'exec'))

<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>name = 'Drew'
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>if name == 'Drew':
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>print 'Hi, %s!' % name
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>else:
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>print 'Greetings, stranger.'
<code object <module> at 0000000002B1DBB0, file "<string>", line 1>@
>>> del y[0]
>>> for line in y:
        exec line

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#308>", line 2, in <module>
    exec line
  File "<string>", line 1
    if name == 'Drew':
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

So as you see, the : character (which is required for selection blocks) causes exec to error. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've attempted to get around this for hours but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it simply not possible?

Thank you very much for reading this and I appreciate all help given to me.

Comment: Why are you using a code object as the input prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in 2.7 when run from an IDLE edit window:

```
line=''
lines = []
print "Enter Python lines (@ to quit):"
while line != '@':
    line=raw_input()
    lines.append(line)
lines.pop() # delete '@' line
lines = '\n'.join(lines)
exec lines
```

The result in the Shell window:

```
>>> 
Enter Python lines (@ to quit):
name = 'Terry'
if name == 'Drew':
  print 'Hi Drew'
else:
  print 'Hi stranger'
@
Hi stranger
```

Note that lines need to be joined with '\n', not ''. Also, after joining, the snippet does not end with '\n'. I believe this may be a problem of with earlier versions of Python, where exec may have needed a terminal '\n' for multiline blocks.

That said, this is an AWFUL way to enter code. It took me three tries to enter the above without error! Much better for both initial entry and editing would be, for instance, a tkinter text box widget.

Comment: This looks like a winner! As far as it being a bad way to enter code, remember it's just the interactive prompt. I prototype in it a lot, then put official code into a program. The program I'm writing now is the world editor, so with that comes the need to write out room descriptions, mob descriptions, etc. I've written my own text editor in the code that accepts input line by line until @ is found. It includes editing commands as well, so if I make a typo I can use a command to fix that specific line. Looks like I'll just need to add the join command and I'm all set!

Comment: Just thought I'd stop by and leave an update. For a while I was having trouble loading up the saved code into my editor... then I realized what I needed to do was to undo the join command by splitting at the newline character. Now everything works as it should, and test runs of code I type into it execute perfectly. Now to build the actual game engine and see how it all works in-game!

Answer (score 4):

You use `exec` to evaluate a single line. In this code:

```
if a == b:
  do_c()
```

The first line, evaluated by itself, is **a syntax error**. The above can be also folded to a single line as:

```
if a == b: do_c()
```

In the more general case, allowing multiple lines, what you could do is collect the whole input into a string (with correct whitespace), then call `exec` on that:

```
source = '''
name = "joe"
if name == "joe":
    print "hi joe"
else:
    print "hi stranger"
'''
exec source
```

You're already figured out to end the input with a special char (`@`), but you should also expect your user to provide correct whitespace for Python if he needs to write multi-line statements.

Comment: You may also want to mention the correct replacement for the final `for` loop in the example code: `exec ''.join(y)`

Comment: @ncoghlan: joining the lines is not the end of the story - AFAICS, his "user" entered the lines without regard for whitespace, so Python still won't parse it

Comment: True, but there's not a lot the application can do about that. And the error messages will be clearer in that case (i.e. "expected indented block" and friends)

Comment: Indeed, I do need to indent. As this was just an interactive prototype, I wasn't paying 100% attention. I did write my own text editor in my program which will be used to enter the code. As the only user is myself, indenting will be something I will keep track of myself. I'll probably throw in a reminder above my text editor to properly indent the code, just in case :)

Comment: @Drew: actually, if the real code is run from a file, you better not use `exec` at all. `import` the file as a module instead - Google for Python plugins - it's actually quite easy to implement, and is much more friendly and safe than `exec`

Comment: Well everything's stored to disk with JSON and then loaded once when you enter that area into 2d dict objs (using defaultdict from collections), then I just reference what I need. I imagine the code looking like, "for line in scripts['1']['code']: exec line". Is this still a problem, or should I look for a different way? I figure if it's a safety issue the only thing that someone might harm if they decide to edit the scripts files is their own computer, since it will be a standalone single-player game.

Comment: @Drew: you just saw that "for line in ... exec line" doesn't really work

Comment: Oh, right! As marked above, I would most likely just need to do "exec script['1']['code']" then.